# Event not fired if Adding NotifyIcon programatically in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to add multiple NotifyIcon programatically. The problem is that only one NotifyIcon can define EventHandler. Other NotifyIcons do not fire the defined EventHandler at all.
If I simply add two NotifyIcon from designer stuff (i.e. using GUI), each EventHandler is called correctly.

But, for example, I did the following code two times for creating two NotifyIcon at the same time.

```
        NotifyIcon notifyIcon1 = new NotifyIcon();
        notifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick);
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        notifyIcon1.Icon = Properties.Resources.test;
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "title";
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "text";
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "title","text", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

I simply generated two NotifyIcon (`notifyIcon1` & `notifyIcon2`) like the above way.
And, both icons are successfully displayed in the right bottom place.
However, one of NotifyIcon does not fire event action, e.g. Mouse Click.
One notifyicon is working fine for Event. But, the other one does not fire MouseDoubleClick event handler defined in the above.

I want to create NotifyIcon programatically. But, if I create NotifyIcons programatically, only one NotifyIcon can fire Event Handle stuff. Other ones never work.

I cannot find some questions or related articles.

```
NotifyIcon notifyIcon2, notifyIcon1;
public void showTest()
{
    notifyIcon1 =
        new NotifyIcon();
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "title";
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "text body";
    notifyIcon1.Text = "text";
    this.notifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(testNotifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick1);

    notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
    notifyIcon1.Text = "test";
    notifyIcon1.Icon = Properties.Resources.test;
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "body";
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "title";
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "title", "body", ToolTipIcon.Info);

    notifyIcon2 =
       new NotifyIcon();
    notifyIcon2.BalloonTipTitle = "title";
    notifyIcon2.BalloonTipText = "text body";
    notifyIcon2.Text = "text";
    this.notifyIcon2.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(testNotifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick2);

    notifyIcon2.Visible = true;
    notifyIcon2.Text = "test";
    notifyIcon2.Icon = Properties.Resources.test;
    notifyIcon2.BalloonTipTitle = "body";
    notifyIcon2.BalloonTipText = "title";
    notifyIcon2.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "title", "body", ToolTipIcon.Info);

 }
private void testNotifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick1(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);

}
private void testNotifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick2(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon2.ShowBalloonTip(1000);

}
```

So, for this code, I just put break point in each MouseDoubleClick handler. But, never hit it. I am using just touch pad in Laptop, i.e. not using some kind of real mouse. I think this is not related at all. But, just in case. And, these method & variables are defined in some class extending From.

Comment: this should work fine. I did it myself, and both events fire. You must be setting something up wrong. Can you post the code for `notifyIcon2`?

Comment: Really? I put the testing codes.

Comment: I tested using your exact code and both the event handlers are called. I'm also using a touch pad. Quite strange why you can't get it to work.

Comment: Um. I am trying to find what is the difference between my code & the created notifyIcon by GUI i.e. designer stuff. THen, I found  this.notifyIcon3 = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(this.components);
           .So, passing components. But, even if I add  this components, this did not work.

Comment: Official Doc says only one balloon can be displayed at one time. So, looks like that I cannot show multiple notifications at one time.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160065(v=vs.110).aspx